# Можно ли с помощью анализа IP сайта узнать тип контента (развлекательный, образовательный)

Tags: веб-программирование, анализ

Можно ли, зная *IP*-адрес сайта, узнать, какой контент предоставляет сайт (развлекательный, образовательный)?
Например, через *WHOIS* получить *IP*-адреса, "пройтись" по ним, как-то проанализировать содержимое сайта. 
Хотя бы чисто теоретически можно ли получить тип контента, предоставляемого сайтом?

Comment: Имея содержимое - можно. Только по IP, не имея никакой информации о том что же там на сайте - нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала стоит отметить, что вам лучше работать не с IP адресами, а с доменами. Это связано с тем, что один IP адрес может обслуживать большое количество сайтов. Это типичная ситуация для shared-хостингов.

Далее, если говорить об оценке содержимого сайта, то существует ряд сервисов, занимающихся анализом контента и катетеризацией сайтов. На вход этим сервисам обычно подается доменное имя, а на выходе получается список категорий сайта, с некоторой вероятностной оценкой. Сразу скажу, что большинство (если не все) таких сервисов платные.

В качестве примера, можно посмотреть на один из сервисов компании "Ашманов и партнеры" (я никак с ними не связан), а именно [Семантическое зеркало](http://sm.ashmanov.com/product/). А вот тут есть [демо версия](http://sm.ashmanov.com/demo/). К примеру, ru.stackoverflow.com, на момент написания ответа, попадает в категорию "Наука и техника" с вероятностью 80.3%

Answer (score 0):

С точностью плюс-минус трамвайная остановка, это можно сделать по доменному имени - com, GOV,  вот это вот все.

В стародавние времена существовали каталоги сайтов. Это дедушки яндекса. Вот они эту функцию и выполняли. В лучшем случае, полуавтоматически.